# Eclipse DDMS not recognizing my Backflip

Tags: android

When I plug my Android Backflip into my computer, WIndows 7 recognizes it but it never shows up in Eclipse's DDMS. I have the USB Debugging checked under Development on the phone and I can see virtual devices I create just fine in DDMS but never anything at all for Backflip.

Does anyone know of something else that needs to be done? I see some things talking about special tasks for Linux but I am running Microsoft Windows 7!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the USB driver for Windows? You can find instructions on how to do so at http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html.

Comment: That was it! It wasn't installed correctly before and took a heck of a long time to get the right driver to install but it's working now.

Thanks.